# To get all the registered Devices in Eclipse Hono Tenant

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-iot

Is there a way to get list of all the Tenants names/id in a Hono server.

Is there a way to get list of all Devices registered in a particular tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the example device registry, that is included in Hono?

The [Management API](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/api/management) of the device registry does not provide such operations. And FMPOV this would violate the tenant separation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let us imagine we have a tenant named "testingTenant" and we have registered 4 devices with device Ids 100,101,102 and 103 respectively. Please let me know if there is any way to query all the devices in this tenat. And in this case, query result should be 4 (including their device Ids)

Comment: The Management API does not currently provide this. If you need such a feature, you can make a feature request. The best way to do this is to open an issue with your proposal on [Github](https://github.com/eclipse/hono), where the Hono community can discuss the idea.